# how to get the no of factors of a number within range?

Tags: factorization

Generally I do prime factorization and get all prime factors and I do permutation and combinations to find all factors.

For example: 1824 is the number I am trying to factors of. Now I need a no factors of 1824 within in number 300.

Is there any trick??

Comment: For your example : what is the range within which you wish to find factors : 1 to 300 ?

Answer (score 1):

One trick, is not searching numbers past the square root of the number you're searching for factors. For example, to find factors from 2-300, you only really need to search from 2-ceil(sqrt(1824)), which is 2-43. Once you find a number in the 2-43 range, divide it into 1824 to check for other factors which may be above 43.

Answer (score 0):

As a brute force solution , you don't need to prime factorize the number for this. You could simply check for all numbers in the range.

Let the range of numbers in which you wish to find factors be [range_start, range_end].
Simply iterate over these numbers in a loop and for each number (say x) , check if (`number % x == 0` ) , if yes , then x is a factor of the number.